Как правильно делать специализацию шаблона?
Пытаюсь сделать по подобию примера из книги, но не получается.

Пробовал разные варианты. И typename Space = int, и class Stack<bool, Space = int>. Ничего не помогает. Ближе всего видимо так:
template <typename T, int Space = 4096>
class Stack
{

};

template <template Space>
class Stack<bool>
{

};

Но как оказалось, даже если точь-в-точь делать, всё равно не работает. Выдаёт - E0707 требуется список параметров шаблона, и E0840 использование списка аргументов шаблона в объявлении основного шаблона не допускается:
template <template T1, template T3>
class Temp <T1, int, T3>
{

};

Может ли это быть опечатка? Или же я что-то упускаю из вида?
UPD. Извиняюсь, что не удачно объяснил. Попытаюсь более развёрнуто. До этого начинал с малого. Вначале написал просто класс Stack, который хранит элементы. Размер у которого был фиксированный. Т.е. объявил приватное поле int space = 20.
Потом добавил шаблон. И отладил его. Версия вида:
template <typename T>
class Stack
{

};

template <>
class Stack<bool>
{

};

работает, но самый последний шаг вызвал наибольшие трудности. Я не могу понять как правильно добавить ещё один параметр, и в шаблон, и в специализацию.

¿Вы точно понимаете, что такое специализация шаблона? ¿Какого конкретного эффекта вы пытаетесь тут достичь (привидите конкретный пример инстанцирования шаблона с параметрами без специализации и со специализацией)?

Для ЧЕГО вы пробовали разные варианты? Исходный шаблон, какую специализацию хотите? ваш вопрос непонятен...

Ну я постараюсь объяснить. Есть класс, который хранит элементы, и проверяет свой размер. Если размер больше разрешённого, то выдаёт исключение. Если пользователь хочет, то задаёт доступный размер, если не хочет, то не задаёт. И шаблон без специализации меня полностью устраивает Stack stack{ 0,1,2,3,4,5 }; А внутри специализации написал так, чтобы на каждые 8 bool объявлялась одна переменная unsigned char. И теперь пытаюсь добиться, чтобы интерфейс для пользователя остался таким же Stack stack{ true, false, true }; Перед этим всё отладил с более простым вариантом, без Space.

Получается тут нужна частичная специализация template<int Space> class Stack<bool, Space> Количество параметров шаблона при специализации не меняется. Только один или несколько из них указываются "более специализированно".

Похоже помогло. Спасибо. Точно пока сказать не могу, потому, что появились новые ошибки. Я для части задач объявил класс Cell, который хранит только одно значение, и указатель на следующую ячейку. И долго не трогал эту часть кода. Теперь почему-то перестала работать функция friend Cell& next_cell(Cell& c) Мне надо ещё помучится с этим.

Не очень понятно все же...
Вы хотите что-то такое?
template <typename T, int Size = 40>
class Stack
{
public:
    Stack() { cout << Size << endl; }
};

template<int Size>
class Stack<bool, Size>
{
public:
    Stack() { cout << "bool " << Size << endl; }

};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    Stack<int> s1;
    Stack<bool,20> s2;
}


Да, такой вариант заработал. Благодарю.

Всем спасибо.
template<int Space>
class Stack<bool, Space>

Решило проблему.

Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, отметьте лучший ответ как принятый (галка напротив выбранного ответа). — из очереди проверок

@чистов_n Это не голое "спасибо", человек наоборот приложил решение, которое ему дали в комментариях.

@HolyBlackCat прошу прощения, буду знать. :)
